# Rack::Chunked is deprecated and will be removed in Rack 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I start my rails app I get:

> /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rack-3.0.7/lib/rack/chunked.rb:6: warning: Rack::Chunked is deprecated and will be removed in Rack 3.1

Not sure how to fix this warning, any idea?

Comment: We'll need a bit more context. What version of Rails?

Comment: @tadman Rails 7.1.0.alpha (from main on github)

Comment: my suggestion would be not to run Rails 7.1.0 alpha... problems such as you are seeing with rack are not unexpected with an alpha release. Either accept the deprecation warning and live with it, until Rails 7.1.0 is released, or revert to the most recent released version of Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to require `Rack::Chuncked` directly in your app, you can require `Rack`. `Rack::Chuncked` is autoloaded in some files like `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb`. `Rack::Chunked` will be completely removed in Rack 3.1 with Rails 8. You can check [this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47078) for more details.